# Python: выполнить replace для отдельного символа из всех элементов списка - что не так?

Tags: python, list, datetime, replace

Есть список с датами формата ДД.ММ.ГГГГ - хочу вместо разделителя "." использовать ", ".
Один из попробованных вариантов:

```
for i in vals_date:
    vals_date[i].replace('.', ', ')
```

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Из-за чего эта ошибка и как мне выполнить эту замену?

Всё это нужно для того, чтобы скормить список с датами модулю datetime.

P.S.:
Спасибо подсказавшим! Получилось с кодом:

```
for i in range(len(vals_date)):
    a.append(vals_date[i].replace('.', ', '))
```

Comment: Ошибка в том, что в цикле вы присваиваете переменной i последовательно значения списка vals_date. а потом пытаетесь обратиться к этому списку указывая значения. надо `for i in range(len(vals_date))`: видимо

Comment: `i` это уже сама дата, а не индекс. И `.replace()` возвращает копию строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vals_date = [...]
replaced_date = [date.replace('.', ', ') for date in vals_date]
```

Comment: Я бы только не `i` переменную назвал, а как-то по-другому. Исторически сложилось, что в программах `i` это обычно некий числовой индекс.

Comment: Ок, так и откорректирую